Does the Apple CloudKit dashboard only show developer data?
I am creating an iOS app.
I saved the data using Realm, but I found CloudKit while I was looking into it because I thought there were many inconveniences with the backup.
I understand that CloudKit doesn't cost anything else and stores users data in users iCloud space.
And I'm looking at CloudKit DashBoard, and I'm only seeing the data of the devices that I ran with my developer account.
And the data of the test account is not displayed.
I don't want to check other users' data.
However, I just want to make sure that CloudKit's Dashboard only inquires about the data stored by the developer.

You can select the development or the production database. When you are in Xcode, the app will use the development db by default. You can force it to use the production db by creating an entry in the entitlement file called;
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment of type string set to
Production
Accounts (Apple IDs) registered in the development account can access their db (both production and development) from the dashboard.
